# Is it possible to detect if you are in the last processing attempt of an specific task?

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

When using push task queues in Google AppEngine, I know we can use the "X-AppEngine-TaskRetryCount" and "X-AppEngine-TaskExecutionCount" request header parameters to tell how many times we have tried to process an specific task.
Is it possible to detect if it's the last attempt or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is to pass the max retry count as a parameter in the HTTP request when you add tasks to TaskQueue. Then, you can detect if is the last attempt comparing the header attribute "X-AppEngine-TaskRetryCount" with your custom param:

```
Boolean isLastAttempt = (taskRetryCount == (maxRetryCount - 1));
```

Not exactly a good design approach though...